# Constraints xcode 8 Beta

Tags: constraints, beta, xcode8

I can't remove a constraint on Xcode 8 beta after I set it.  I use to with the resolve auto layout issues button on the bottom right coroner.(the one that looks like a tie fighter).  Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: It's a bug, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101715/how-to-delete-constraints-from-main-storyboard-with-xcode-8-beta

Answer (score -1):

If you need to remove a constraint, double click it on the element's ruler view. You should see the constraint properties, then hit the backspace key.