# How to delete Constraints from Main.storyboard with Xcode 8 beta?

Tags: autolayout, xcode8

I try with backspace how it was on swift 2 but in Xcode 8 beta I can't do it the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double click the constraint in the Right Pane (Size Inspector). This will then show the constraint in the left pane. You can delete the constraint from the left pane by using backspace.

[image]

Comment: OP said that backspace doesn't delete anymore.

Comment: Backspace doesn't delete in the right pane, but in the left pane it will. Try it yourself.

Comment: Yeah this is definitely a bug. I've just been clicking the "installed" button to remove them temporarily but I'm glad to actually remove them